# How to interpret probability density function of transformed variable?

Tags: probability, derivatives, image-processing

I am currently reading [digital image processing by Rafael c. Gonzalez](http://web.ipac.caltech.edu/staff/fmasci/home/astro_refs/Digital_Image_Processing_2ndEd.pdf) (pdf link page 92 in page and 103 in pdf, equation 3.3-3). 
Basically what it says is if:

r : denotes the intensities of an image and has range  [ $0$ - ($L-1$)].

s = $T(r)$

Let $p_s$(r) and $p_s$(s)  denote the PDFs of r and s.

A fundamental result from basic probability theory is that if $p_s$(r) and $p_s$(s) are known and $T(r)$ is continuous and differentiable over the range of values of interest then the PDF of the transformed (mapped) variable $s$ can be obtained using simple formula.

$p_s$(s) = $p_s$(r)$|$$\frac{dr}{ds}$$|$

Where did this simple formula came from? I am trying to wrap my head around where did $|$$\frac{dr}{ds}$$|$  came from?

Comment: @dimebucker91 I was taking time to understand for this many days :) . Yes your answer solved my problem.

Comment: It might be useful for you to read https://fsalamri.files.wordpress.com/2015/02/casella_berger_statistical_inference1.pdf , if not all of it, at least the first 4 chapters. Transformation of variables is covered in chapter 4

Comment: oh nice! thank you for the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a general result for the transformation of a random variable. If we have two random variables $X$, $Y = g(X)$ with probability distribution functions $f_X(x)$, $f_Y(y)$ where $g$ is monotone. Along with some other technical conditions regarding the derivatives of $g^{-1}(y)$, the PDF of $Y$ is:

$$
f_Y(y) = 
\begin{cases}
f_X(g^{-1}(y)) |   \frac{d}{dy} g^{-1}(y) | \quad\text{     if       } y \in  \mathcal{Y}\\
0 \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

To see why this holds, note that if $g$ is increasing, then:

\begin{align*}
f_Y(y) = \frac{d}{dy}F_Y(y) \overset{\text{(1)}}{=} \frac{d}{dy} F_X(g^{-1}(y)) = f_X(g^{-1}(y)) \frac{d}{dy} g^{-1}(y)
\end{align*}

if $g$ is decreasing, then

$$
f_Y(y) = -f_X(g^{-1}(y)) \frac{d}{dy} g^{-1}(y)
$$

So the general result follows easily.

In your case, $r = T^{-1}(s)$. When working with multivariate distributions we have a more general expression involving the Jacobian rather than the derivative

To see why (1) holds, assume $g$ increasing:

\begin{align*}
F_Y(y) &= P(Y \le y)\\
&= P(g(X) \le y) \\
& = P(X \le g^{-1}(y))\\
&= F_X(g^{-1}(y))
\end{align*}

Source:
[https://www.amazon.com/Statistical-Inference-George-Casella/dp/0534243126](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0534243126)

Comment: $g$ is continuous?  It's said in the linked pdf that $T^{-1}$ might not be single-valued.

Comment: the result only holds if $T^{-1}(s)$ is single valued and monotone in $s \in [0,1]$, which is condition (a) in the link you mention

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: \begin{align*}
 \frac{d}{dy} F_X(g^{-1}(y)) = f_X(g^{-1}(y)) \frac{d}{dy} g^{-1}(y)
\end{align*} How did this happen? what property of derivative is used here?

Comment: chain rule: $\frac{d}{dx}f(g(x)) = f'(g(x)) g'(x)$